# Swift associated type is ambiguous

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, swift-protocols, ambiguous, associated-types

I have written a protocol that has two associated types. When I want to create an instance of one of the associated type in a default implementation of a function the compiler complains with: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

```swift
protocol Node: Equatable {
    
    associatedtype Identifier: Equatable
    associatedtype SomeEdge: Edge
    
    var identifier: Identifier { get }
    var edges: [SomeEdge] { get set }
    
    init(_ identifier: Identifier)
    
    mutating func addEdge(to: Self)
    mutating func delete(_: SomeEdge)
}

extension Node {
    mutating func addEdge(to other: Self) {
        let edge = SomeEdge(source: self, destination: other)    // Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
        
        guard !edges.contains(edge) else {
            return
        }
        
        edges.append(edge)
    }
    
    mutating func delete(_ edge: SomeEdge) {
        guard let index = edges.firstIndex(of: edge) else {
            return
        }
        
        edges.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What is `Edge`? Can you add its code as well?

Comment: @pawello2222 `Edge` is another protocol.

Comment: @macintosh_HD could you please post also `Edge` protocol code?

Comment: I'm having trouble imaging an `Edge` protocol where this would work (the `init` requirement does not look like something that can be fulfilled). I strongly suspect you're using protocols where you really should use generic structs. Why are Node and Edge protocols?